# Does VirtualProtect need some privileges

Tags: winapi, api-hook

I am trying to implement an IAT hook. I wrote the IAT part in a dll, and the injection part in an exe with CreateRemoteThread. I found after I injected the dll, the VirtualProtect function in IAT part always threw an ERROR_INVALID_PRAMETER, even I passed the paramters with values just returned from VirtualQuery. I have no idea that what have happened. Does the VirtualProtect need some privileges that I do not have?

Here is the error part:

```
if (0 == lstrcmpA(lpApiName, (LPCSTR)pImport->Name)){

                MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION thunkMemInfo;
                DWORD junk;
                DWORD oldProtect;
                if (!VirtualQuery(thunk, &thunkMemInfo, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION))){
                    return GetLastError();
                }

                if (!VirtualProtect(thunkMemInfo.BaseAddress, thunkMemInfo.RegionSize, thunkMemInfo.Protect, &oldProtect)){
                   return GetLastError();  -------Here returns 87 in decimal
                }

                MessageBoxA(NULL, "aaaa", "Hooked", MB_OK);
                thunk->u1.Function = (DWORD)Callback;
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "bbbbb", "Hooked", MB_OK);

                if (!VirtualProtect(&thunk, thunkMemInfo.RegionSize, oldProtect, &junk)){
                    return 3;
                }

                return S_OK;
            }
```

And my injection part in C# is like this:

```
public static void InjectDLL(IntPtr hProcess, String strDLLName, Process proc)
    {
        IntPtr bytesout;

        // Length of string containing the DLL file name +1 byte padding
        Int32 LenWrite = strDLLName.Length + 1;
        // Allocate memory within the virtual address space of the target process
        IntPtr AllocMem = (IntPtr)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, (IntPtr)null, (uint)LenWrite, 0x1000, 0x40); //allocation pour WriteProcessMemory

        // Write DLL file name to allocated memory in target process
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, AllocMem, strDLLName, (UIntPtr)LenWrite, out bytesout);
        // Function pointer "Injector"
        UIntPtr Injector = (UIntPtr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        if (Injector == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Injector Error! \n ");
            // return failed
            return;
        }

        // Create thread in target process, and store handle in hThread
        IntPtr hThread = (IntPtr)CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, (IntPtr)null, 0, Injector, AllocMem, 0, out bytesout);
        // Make sure thread handle is valid
        if (hThread == null)
        {
            //incorrect thread handle ... return failed
            Console.WriteLine(" hThread [ 1 ] Error! \n ");
            return;
        }
        // Time-out is 10 seconds...
        int Result = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10 * 1000);
        // Check whether thread timed out...
        if (Result == 0x00000080L || Result == 0x00000102L || Result == 0xFFFFFFFFL)
        {
            /* Thread timed out... */
            Console.WriteLine(" hThread [ 2 ] Error! \n ");
            // Make sure thread handle is valid before closing... prevents crashes.
            if (hThread != null)
            {
                //Close thread in target process
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
            return;
        }
        // Sleep thread for 1 second
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // Clear up allocated space ( Allocmem )
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, AllocMem, (UIntPtr)0, 0x8000);
        // Make sure thread handle is valid before closing... prevents crashes.
        if (hThread != null)
        {
            //Close thread in target process
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        // return succeeded
        ResumeThread(hThread);
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Inject!");
        return;
    }


Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(exeName)[0];
           // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(proc.ProcessName + "Start!");
            uint dwAccl = 0x0002 | 0x0400 | 0x0008 | 0x0010 |0x0020;
            InjectDLL((IntPtr)tools.OpenProcess(dwAccl, 1, proc.Id), "Loader.dll", proc);
```

Comment: You must *always* check the return value of winapi functions.  Like OpenProcess().  Failure to do so only ever produces SO questions.  That (IntPtr) cast is fundamentally wrong as well, it isn't declared correctly.  And you are using the wrong winapi functions, messing with another process requires VirtualQueryEx and VirtualProtectEx, they take the process handle.

Comment: @HansPassant Why is the (IntPtr) cast wrong ? If I'm not mistaken he is using a `HANDLE`, whose equivalent in C# is `IntPtr`.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, I forgot to provide the OpenProcess(). It is 
  
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
            UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
            Int32 bInheritHandle,
            Int32 dwProcessId
            );

Comment: What is the value of `thunkMemInfo.State` before `VirtualProtect` ?

Comment: @ElderBug  Hi, the thunkMeminfo.State is 0x1000

Comment: @Lord_WayneY And what is `thunk` ? How is it defined and what is assigned to it ?

Answer (score 0):

`VirtualProtect(thunkMemInfo.BaseAddress, thunkMemInfo.RegionSize, thunkMemInfo.Protect, &oldProtect`

The third argument:
thunkMemInfo.Protect

This is not a new memory protection constant, this is the one that you retrieved with VirtualQuery, all your doing is applying the same protection.

Change it to PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE (0x40) instead